# How to list groups and counts of uncompleted tasks?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two db tables:

```
tasks:
task_id (unique id, autoincrement)
group_id (from the next table: groups, where task belongs to)
task_name
status (if task has been completed or not)

groups:
group_id (unique id, autoincrement)
group_name
```

My goal is to list all groups along with number of uncompleted tasks in them (task status 0). 
I achieve that by this query:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT g.id, g.name, count(g.id) as count
FROM task_groups g, tasks t
WHERE g.status = 0 AND t.group =  g.id AND t.status = 0
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY g.id ASC";
```

And I get results like this:

```
Group1  3 uncompleted
Group2 13 uncompleted
Group3 30 uncompleted
```

But empty task groups (there are no any tasks that belong to a specific group) are not being listed.

Result should be like this:

```
Group1  3 uncompleted
Group2 13 uncompleted
Group3 30 uncompleted
Group4  0 uncompleted
Group5  0 uncompleted
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. `GROUP BY` the group, but instead of counting the group id, try instead doing a `SUM` on tasks that are incomplete, like this:

```
SELECT g.id, g.name,
SUM(IF(t.status = 0, 1, 0)) incomplete_tasks
FROM task_groups g
LEFT JOIN tasks t ON (t.group_id = g.id)
GROUP BY g.id ASC
HAVING incomplete_tasks > 0;
```

Omit the `HAVING` clause if you want to list *all* task groups.

*Note: I didn't see the purpose of `g.status` in your query, and `status` wasn't listed as a column in the `groups` table so I've left it out of my example.*

Comment: That's the required solution. Btw the g.status is not relevant here so you were right for ommiting it.